# springboot+mybatis multi-module project maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, mybatis, multi-module

Below picture is my project structure.
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRNJn.png)

parent project is demo-mybatis sub module are mybatis-dao,demo-service.
demo-mybatis pom.xml below:

4.0.0
pom

mybatis-dao
demo-service
demo-mybatis-app


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.2.RELEASE
 

com.example
demo-mybatis
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
demo-mybatis
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

mybatis-dao UserMapper.java interface:
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserMapper {
    List selectByName(String name);
    int insert(User user);
    void update(User user);
    void delete(Long id);
    User verify(User user);
    List select();
}
```

```
demo-service UserServiceImpl.java class :
```

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Resource
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public List selectByName(String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int insert(User user) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

````
run application class :
``` @SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example","com.wjs"})
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true)
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"com.wjs.model.dao"})
public class DemoMybatisAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoMybatisAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
````

application.properties ：

```
server.port=8002
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.application.name=demo-mybatis
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.type=com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:mapper/*.xml
mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.wjs.model.entity
```

always exception below :
I can not find why?
I try this:

```
    @Resource
    private UserMapper userMapper;
```

question is :

```
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'userMapper' is expected to be of type 'com.wjs.model.dao.UserMapper' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55'
```

and

```
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;
```

question is :

```
 No qualifying bean of type 'com.wjs.model.dao.UserMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I'm crazy

Comment: it 's a maven project created by IntelliJ IEDA , springboot+mybatis dao service mult-module.
```  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>mybatis-dao</module>
        <module>demo-service</module>
        <module>demo-mybatis-app</module>
    </modules>
```

Comment: The error message itself is not very useful. Please add the full stack trace. It would be the best if you could share that projects on GitHub.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'userMapper' is expected to be of type 'com.example.mapper.UserMapper' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57'
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]

Comment: https://github.com/shinebar/demo-mybatis.git   project git address,thx.

Comment: Have you tried removing `EnableCaching`?

Comment: @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example","com.wjs"})
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true)
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"com.wjs.model.dao"})
public class DemoMybatisAppApplication {}  yes ,i tried adding EnableCaching.but the quetion is the same.

Comment: I tried adding or removing  @EnableCaching/@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true).but the quetion is the same.

Comment: Your mapper should be annotated `@Mapper` not `@Repository` to take advantage of the mybatis spring starter.  Or an `@Component` injecting `SqlSession`.

Comment: ```@kendavidson
@Mapper 
public interface UserMapper

Description:The bean 'userMapper' could not be injected as a 'com.example.mapper.UserMapper' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:Action:Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.

Answer (score 0):

@Mapper
public interface UserMapper

Description:

The bean 'userMapper' could not be injected as a 'com.example.mapper.UserMapper' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:

Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.